Diffusion PM: Remove the edge effect at t = 0
In DPM paper appendix B.2 for proving that the $\int d\mathrm{x}^{(0)} d\mathrm{x}^{(1)} q(\mathrm{x}^{(0)}, \mathrm{x}^{(1)}) log [\displaystyle \frac{\pi(\mathrm{x}^{(0)})}{\pi(\mathrm{x}^{(1)})}] $is zero, the author uses the fact from the design of process that $\int d\mathrm{x}^{(t)} q(\mathrm{x}^{(t)}) log \pi(\mathrm{x}^{(t)}) = \int d\mathrm{x}^{(t)} \pi(\mathrm{x}^{(t)}) log \pi(\mathrm{x}^{(t)}) = -H[X^{T}] $ is a constant for all $t$.

My problem is that I don't understand why and How this fact is true. Can someone explain the reasoning behind this step and how the equality is derived?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I recently have the same problem too, and searched this question. Since I solved it and in case someone who also suffer from this, I will post the answer below. Let me use subscript instead of superscript for convenience.
First, We need to prove the fact $CE(p, q) = H(p)$ when $H(p) = H(q)$ for $p \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_p, \sigma_p)$ and $q \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_q, \sigma_q)$.
Prove:
By definition
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_p &= - \int p(x) \log p(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= E_p[-\log p(x)] \\
&= E_p\left[ -\log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_p^2}} \exp\left(-\frac 1 {2\sigma_p^2} (x-\mu_p)^2 \right) \right) \right] \\
&= E_p\left[ \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma_p^2) + \frac 1 {2\sigma_p^2} (x-\mu_q)^2 \right] \\
& = \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma_p^2) + \frac 1 {2\sigma_p^2} E_p[(x-\mu_p)^2] \\
& = \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma_p^2) + \frac 1 2 
\end{aligned}
$$
and similarly
$$
H_q = \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma_q^2) + \frac 1 2
$$
Thus, $H(p) = H(q)$ implies $\sigma_p = \sigma_q$. And then the cross entropy is
$$
\begin{aligned}
CE(p, q) &= -\int q(x) \log p(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= E_q \left[ - \log p(x) \right] \\
&= E_q \left[ - \log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac 1 {2\sigma^2} (x-\mu_p)^2 \right) \right) \right] \\
&= E_q \left[ \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma^2) + \frac 1 {2\sigma^2} (x-\mu_p)^2 \right] \\
&= \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma^2) + \frac 1 {2\sigma^2} E_q[(x-\mu_p)^2] \\
&= \frac 1 2 \log(2\pi \sigma^2) + \frac 1 2
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $\sigma = \sigma_p = \sigma_q$，Then $CE(p, q) = H(p)$.
Second, we will prove $\int q(x_0, x_1) \log\left(p(x_0) / p(x_1) \right) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1= 0$.
Prove:
$$
\int q(x_0, x_1) \log\left(p(x_0) / p(x_1) \right) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1 = \int q(x_0, x_1) \log(p(x_0)) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1 - \int q(x_0, x_1) \log(p(x_1)) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1
$$
The first item is
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int q(x_0, x_1) \log(p(x_0)) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1 &=  \int q(x_1 \mid x_0) q(x_0) \log(p(x_0)) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1\\
 &= \int q(x_1\mid x_0) \mathrm{d} x_1 \int q(x_0) \log(p(x_0)) \mathrm{d} x_0 \\
 &= CE(p, q)
 \end{aligned}
$$
Where we use the fact that $\int q(x_1\mid x_0) \mathrm{d} x_1 = 1$. And similarly, the second item is also $CE(p, q)$. Thus,
$$\int q(x_0, x_1) \log\left(p(x_0) / p(x_1) \right) \mathrm{d} x_0 \mathrm{d}x_1= 0$$
That's all.
